# Different validation on insert and edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using DataAnotation for validation and i need disable it of in some cases.

F.E. on create i need user insert password and confirmation, but for edit it can stay empty and not changed.

I have this model:

```
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Re-enter Password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation do not match.")]
        public string PasswordControl { get; set; }
```

Enought vould be disable required on password on edit.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there are two ways, either will work.

1. Use different model for edit and insert. I prefer and use this one in my application. It's easy and future proof(Edit and insert models and rules may be quite different).
2. Customize a `ValidationAttribute` and override `IsValid` method. Use some context such as `IsEdit` field of your model. It can be used since MVC3. See the "Model Validation Improvements" part of this article http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx